# How to format a sub list with Markdown on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, markdown

I tried this

```
1. Bullet one.
1.1. Bullet one. one.
1.2. Bullet one. two.
2. Bullet two
```

And that doesn't work.

I'm not sure if it's been documented [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list) and [here](http://www.tumblr.com/help) :-/

How to format a sub list with Markdown on Tumblr?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't use Tumblr myself, but on all other markdown-using sites that I'm familiar with (StackExchance included), the syntax

```
1. Bullet one.
 1. Bullet one. one.
 2. Bullet one. two.
2. Bullet two
```

gives the result you're looking for as far as generating correct HTML is concerned:

1. Bullet one.

   1. Bullet one. one.
   2. Bullet one. two.
2. Bullet two

The appearance of the list once you've defined it as being one is outside the scope of Markdown. That's controlled by editing your CSS. (Assuming you CAN edit your Tumblr theme. Again, I've never used it.)

If you want the `1.1.` format for nested lists, there are instructions for suitably standards-compliant browsers on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1/4098296#4098296). (Which basically means no IE6 or IE7 and the workaround for them either requires ditching Markdown or writing some Javascript for your template)

Comment: ssokolow Thanks, man! That's working!

Answer (score 2):

For unordered lists:

```
- an entry
- another entry
 - some sub entry without leading bullet
- - some sub entry with leading bullet
 - another entry for another entry
 - - blablabla
 - - blublublu
 - - - dfdf
- - - - also some way
```

**Result**:

- an entry
- another entry

  - some sub entry without leading bullet
- - some sub entry with leading bullet
  - another entry for another entry
  - - blablabla
  - - blublublu
  - - - dfdf
- - - - also some way